# Building json array using spring mvc

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc

How do I build the below JSON array using spring MVC? I want to return the below JSON array as json response using Responsebody. Or can I use the `javax.json` api to build the below JSON array.

```
 {
                        'DemoOrg' : {
                            'West' : {
                                'Alaska' : {
                                    'Denali' : [ "Unit1", "Unit2" ],
                                    'Anchorage' : [ "Unit3", "Unit4" ],

                                },
                                'Arizona' : {
                                    'CottonWood' : [ "Unit5", "Unit6" ],
                                    'Winslow' : [ "Unit7", "Unit8" ],
                                }

                            }

                        },
                        'TestOrg' : {
                            'SouthWest' : {
                                'Missouri' : {
                                    'Kansas City' : [ "Unit9", "Unit10" ],
                                    'Columbia' : [ "Unit11", "Unit12" ],

                                },
                                'Arkansas' : {
                                    'Baxer' : [ "Unit13", "Unit14" ],
                                    'Benton' : [ "Unit15", "Unit16" ],
                                }

                            }

                        }
                    };
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all add this to your pom.xml file:

```
<!-- Jackson JSON Mapper -->
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
 </dependency>
```

Then you have to define MessageConverter. Since you are using *annotated configuration* it should look like this

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.myapp.*")
public class AppConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    // you config stuff

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(new ResourceHttpMessageConverter());
        converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
        super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
    }
}
```

`MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` will convert your Object to JSON.

Comment: I don't want to use jackson instead I want to leave it to spring to convert it as JSON array

Comment: @VijayM it does not matter which library you are using. If your spring release contains own json serialization library, so do not import jackson.

Answer (score 0):

To return an array as JSON response, you need to create a model class which holds the values of the json object. Let the name of the class be ModelOrg.
Then you can return the json response using the following code:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/orgclasses", method= RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<ModelOrg> findAllOrgClasses()
{
    List<ModelOrg> orgclasses = new ArrayList<ModelOrg>();

    ModelOrg testOrg = new ModelOrg();
    //  Set all values in testOrg
    orgclasses.add(testOrg);

    ModelOrg demoOrg = new ModelOrg();
    //  Set all values in demoOrg
    orgclasses.add(demoOrg);

    return orgclasses;

}
```

For this to work you need to add jackson-mapper-asl, xstream, spring-oxm dependencies in pom.xml. Also you need to configure servlet in web.xml, to support json response:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>orgClassesServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.json</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

where orgClassesServlet our servlet.